# View.hasWindowFocus = false after closing a Dialog

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an Activity that has an editText. When click on the editText, a dialog will display to require account verification first. After finishing the account verification, the dialog will close then we will back to the Activity and focus on the editText but the keyboard does not show up even though I have called InputMethodManager.showSoftInput()

I have checked the reason, It did not show the keyboard because of View.hasWindowFocus() = false
How do I make it return true to show the keyboard

Comment: what parameter do you use in showSoftInput()?
I use it like this and it works fine for me
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)

Comment: @MasterZzzing I am using the same function as you. The showSoftInput function requires both view focus and window focus to return true to show the keyboard. But in my case, the window focus returns false

Comment: Have you tried to call editText.requestFocus() before calling InputMethodManager.showSoftInput()? I believe the keyboard won't be triggered if editText.hasFocus() returns false.

Comment: @MasterZzzing I have called the requestFocus() before calling the showKeyboard()